Proper modelling of long range interactions in Ising chain
I am interested in the finite range Ising ring with a constant, not decaying, interaction in a certain coupling range. Thus, working with the Hamiltonian:
$\mathcal{H}=-\frac{J}{2}\sum\limits_{i,j}s_is_j \quad j\in [i-R, i+R],\; j\neq i,\; s_{N+1}=s_{1}$
I couldn't find any reference to this configuration in the literature, as all range interactions I could find refer to a decaying interaction with the distance $|i-j|$. I wonder if this is well defined such that we can still refer to it as an Ising model.

I can't see why it wouldn't be well defined. In terms of why there may not be much literature on it, for finite $R$ in the thermodynamic limit it is still a short range interaction, so I suspect that it looks qualitatively similar to the Ising model with next-nearest neighbor terms (which in turn only look so different from nearest neighbor Ising models)

This type of interactions are a particular instance of "Kac interactions". The main interest of the latter is that, letting $R\to\infty$ after taking the thermodynamic limit $N\to\infty$ yields (rigorously) the corresponding mean-field quantities. One can then study such systems for very large, but finite $R$ as perturbations of the mean-field Ising model. Well, at least in dimensions $2$ and more, since the 1d model will always be disordered for finite $R$... A nice reference is Presutti's book.
